# Plugin: The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type

Tags: c#, sql, plugins, entity-framework-6

I know this topic has been discussed several times but I think my case is a bit different and hopefully solvable in an easy way.

I'm writing a plugin for the software WireCAD which is an open electrical engineering software. Now I've added additional tables in which we can manage some additional features for our company.

The plugin gets loaded when the software is started and can contain multiple forms. If I open one the form were I'm calling the database through entity framework everything works fine.

However when I close the form and reopen the form `within the same instance of the software I get the following error (entity framework 6)

The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'BtuProfile'. Previously found CLR type 'Test.Profile', newly found CLR type 'Test.Profile'.

This is caused because I opened the form twice without somehow remove the previous CLR types. So I was wondering is there a way to unload/lose the previously CLR Type when the form is closed. So when user open the form again there is no previous CLR type?

If this is not possible is there any other way to fix this issue?

Thank you.